# How can I use campaign field with lead report?

Tags: reporting, leads, campaign

Is there a way to include the campaign value that a lead is associated with in a report. Would I have to add a custom field to do the campaign lookup on the lead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you have campaigns with Lead report, but not the other way around. Creating a custom field would be the easiest. If you need it super urgent without going through deployment (or) a one time report you are looking for, I would export a

- Lead report
- Campaign with lead report

Do a vlookup in excel and fill in the campaign related to the lead.

Comment: Not sure what I would vlookup off to join them?

Comment: @Miklr you can use lead ID as a common key for both the reports.

Comment: true, since it's campaign with lead, sorry.